# Mobile site with codeigniter sharing resources

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile

I have a desktop version of a site built with codeigniter ,and am creating the mobile version.
I create a sub domain, m.xyz.com whose document root is public_html/m
I have also place an index.php file in the /m folder
and edited the $system_folder and $application_folder to point the application and system folder of the desktop site in order to share controllers and models.
But when i try out the mobile domain, it still renders the desktop site.
What do i need to do to fix this

Comment: You need to create mobile views... and check whether it's a mobile device in the controller and render the mobile views.

Comment: Thanks man, i thought i was gonna to have mess with index.php file or something

Answer (score 2):

Use the User Agent Class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html

Use this in your controller to determine whether or not the user is on a mobile device:

```
if($this->agent->is_mobile())
{
 // handle mobile devices
}
```

And then render your mobile views inside the if.